# How to insert session *username* in database sql when click logout

Tags: php

im new in php and sql please help me find away to insert a username into sql when click the logout.

heres my code:

```
 <?php

include('includes/mysql_connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$query = mysql_query("select users from username where username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
mysql_query($query);

$insert_log="INSERT INTO activity_logout(username, details) VALUES('$query','Succesfully Logout!')";
mysql_query($insert_log);

}

session_start();
session_destroy();
header("location:index.php");

?>
```

Comment: So, what happens when you run your code? Does it do nothing? The wrong thing? Give you an error message? What is the code supposed to do? What does it actually do? Do your SQL queries get generated correctly? Do they run correctly?

Comment: I hope you dont allow usernames like `1' or '1'='1`, though I suspect your query's wont INSERT them anyways ;p

Comment: it doesnt insert the username of the client when i click the logout button.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do the SELECT because you already have the username, and you should be checking for the `$_SESSION['username']` not if a Submit button is set.

And your open to SQL injection for usernames that are actually SQL query's, or at minimum a username with a `'` in it will break your query.

```
<?php
session_start();
include('includes/mysql_connect.php');

if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO activity_logout 
                        (username, details) 

                 VALUES ("'.mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['username']).'", 
                         "Succesfully Logout!")');
}

session_destroy();
exit(header("location: ./index.php"));
?>
```

---

**Obligatory suggestion**, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/871050). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: THANKS ALOT MATE! THANK THANK YOU! IT PERFECTLY WORKS!

Comment: IF I CAN ONLY GIVE YOU A +1 REP! I NEED +15 REP TO GIVE YOU 1. :(

Comment: no probs, no need to shout ;p just accept it with the tick, if it has helped.

Comment: @LozCheroneツ - would you mind not using shortened URLs? I've unshortened these same URLs a number of times now...

Comment: This is whats wrong with the PHP tag, because its so popular you write answer's and your lucky if you even get an upvote more like a downvote, then the next day you get some spelling or now link nazi making changes. But in the C tag your write a lame answer and get upvoted 30 times.

Comment: @MichaelKohne may i ask why not shortened URLs ? AFAIK its perfectly fine but if its not would you mind either show us related meta post or just stop editing it(may be you can if you have got time :P)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя - There have been several discussions on Meta about this (including [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services) one). Short URLs are more likely to break in the future (Yahoo turned theirs off not long ago), and they prevent the clicking user from seeing where they are going. They are not necessary in SO (there's no length limit) so they have lots of negative with effectively no positive.

Comment: @MichaelKohne I understand your point now, wish you originally made it ekk, ill fix my copy&paste notice for the future posts. Though its too long by 71 characters for a comment now, so ill keep the original for comments, and long version for answers ;p

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
<?php

include('includes/mysql_connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$insert_log="INSERT INTO activity_logout(username, details) VALUES($_SESSION['username'],'Succesfully Logout!')";
mysql_query($insert_log);


}
  session_destroy();
  header("location:index.php");

?>
```

Please use

```
session_start();
```

at the start, after your "login" code. Also, you should use some common file which will handle your includes files. Please refer 
 [enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php)

Comment: Can I know the reason for devoting?

Comment: Are you sure that `$_SESSION['username']` will get interpolated properly in the SQL string?

Comment: True! My fault! I should have escaped the variable.